Transition sentence at the end of the last body paragraph leading into the concluding paragraph?
So I'm writing an essay and we have to use transition sentences between paragraphs. I understand how this would work between body paragraphs/points 1-2 and 2-3 since each is a distinct point but I'm wondering if it's possible to use a transition sentence between the last body paragraph and the concussion? I'm a bit confused since the conclusion is not a point in and of itself but rather a summary of the entire essay. For those of you who may say, just restate your thesis, I'm reserving this for the first/ topic sentence of the conclusion and even if I wasn't it wouldn't make sense to put in the last sentence of my last/third body paragraph. Any advice is appreciated on whether or not this would be possible. If so, how? Thanks!

Have you tried asking your teacher? Because that is what they are for: to teach you how to write.

My teacher says you can do either one so I'm just seeing if anyone has any suggestions....

Either of what? I cannot identify two options in your question body.

Will you please re-phrase '… between the last body paragraph and the concussion…'? Did you mean 'conclusion' or what?

Where did your teacher get the idea there might be a transitional sentence at the end of any earlier paragraph leading into any later paragraph?
Where did your teacher get the idea there might be different kinds of paragraphs: final, penultimate or otherwise?

If the specific purpose of your essay is to demonstrate how well you understand the use of transition sentences, then you could use something formulaic like "In conclusion, there are a number of reasons why [restate your thesis]", and follow this with your concluding paragraph(s).
However, while good essay writing should follow accepted norms, it should never be formulaic. If you're simply writing a general essay, the only purpose of your final transition sentence is to give notice to the reader that your argument is complete and that what is about to follow is a recapitulation. This might be useful if you're trying to meet a minimum page or word count and you need some extra padding; or, if there have been multiple paragraphs supporting your final point and you want to signal that you're now moving to your conclusion. But if you're close to your word limit, or your reader will easily understand that you've made your final point, then you should be direct and economical with your words. Instead of a full transition sentence, a brief phrase may be all the signal your reader needs as you commence the final paragraph. For example...

In conclusion, Abib's contention that air is a liquid is incorrect
because: [dot points 1, 2 & 3].


To transition between your last body paragraph and conclusion, you might describe how your last body paragraph rounds out your final point. You may also describe how your final point adds to your argument as a whole. In this way, you will naturally lead your reader to the conclusion.
Why are such transitions important? Using transition sentences, you guide your reader. When you use one at the end of a paragraph, you help your reader answer the following questions: 'What did I just read? How does it relate to the current subheading? How does this paragraph contribute to the article's objective? Where are we going next?'
How will such a transition help your reader? Your article should take your readers on a journey. In On Writing Well, for example, William Zinsser notes that a reader can become lost when a writer neglects transitions. Like a signpost that shows tourists how to find their way, your transitions should ensure that your readers never feel lost on their journey.
What transitions should you use? Where should you put them? You need to know your target audience well. Then you can anticipate what questions they will be asking throughout your article and what guidance they will need. You also need to know your objective. That way, you can make sure your signposts contribute to your objective.
When you use transitions such as the one you mentioned, you leave clear signposts for your reader and give your article coherent structure.

Your answer is very general and explains what transition sentences are and what purpose they serve, but it doesn't seem to address OP's special case, that is, the transtion between body paragraph and concluding paragraph. Could you say something about that?

Thanks, Ben. Edited post
